# Are there any common informal terms for referring to corrupt politicians?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, pejorative-language, epithet-requests, portuguese

I’m Brazilian and I’m curious to know of common English expressions use to refer to corrupt politicians. Here we use the idiomatic expression *ficha suja*, which literally translated would be something like “dirty card”.

What single words (nouns or adjectives) or idiomatic expressions in English might roughly correspond to that Portuguese term, and which are in everyday casual use somewhere in the English-speaking world?

Comment: I think the word for an evil and corrupt politician is "politician".